# Euler 5: Generalizing

Tags: python

I am trying to get this more generalized way of figuring out Project Euler problem 5.

Question being asked:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers
>   from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all
>   of the numbers from 1 to 20?

This is my code that gives strange results
When I use num1 = 1 and num2 = 10, I get 1260: half the right answer. When I use num1 = 1 and num2 = 20, I get 1/4 the right answer of 232792560.

```
num1 = int(input("Input lower range of primes: "))
num2 = int(input("Input upper range of primes: "))

def primes(num1,num2):
    list_primes = []
    for i in range(num1,num2 + 1):
        for a in range(2,i):
            if i % a == 0:
                break
        else:
            list_primes.append(i)

    return list_primes

primex = primes(num1, num2)

prod = 1
for p in primex:
    n = 2
    prod *= p
    while (p**n < (num2 + 1)):
        prod *= p
        n += 1
        break
print(primex)
print(prod)
```

This code i borrowed from gives out the right results

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
prod = 1 
for p in primes:
    n = 2
    prod *= p
    while (p**n < 21):
        prod *= p
        n += 1

print(prod)
```

Comment: What does the question ask you to do? What are the correct results? What are the results you are getting? Edit your question to address these things, and we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main mistake is that you break out of the `while` loop after a single iteration.  Therefore, you come up short for any prime factors of degree greater than 2.  In these cases, you use 2^2 as the highest factor of 2, when the correct quantities are 2^3 for 10, and 2^4 for 20.  If you go to 30, you'll also be short for 3 (squared instead of cubed).

Simply remove the `break` statement; it's not in the code you borrowed.

Also, use `2` as the lower limit; by starting at `1`, you include that as a prime number.  This will make your `while` loop run forever, as `p**n` is 1 for all values of `n`.

Output of original code (10)

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
1260
```

Output of repaired code (10)

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
2520
```

Output of repaired code (10)

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
232792560
```